# Regex work in Expresso but not in PHP (using preg_match_all)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

First, I am not very good in regex so there may be a mistake in here. I got the following regex pattern I created :

```
`(?:\\&|[^&])*` (PHP : `/(?:\\&|[^&])*/s`)
```

to parse the kind of the following string :

```
hfghfg=hfghfg&gfdgdf=4343543&gfdgfdgfd=fsdfds\&hghg999
```

Espresso give me this :

```
hfghfg=hfghfg
NULL
gfdgdf=4343543
NULL
gfdgfdgfd=fsdfds\&hghg999
NULL
```

So it does the same as `explode('&', $String)` but if `\& is found`, it won't cut.

But in PHP, `preg_match_all` and `preg_match` give me this :

```
preg_match_all('/(?:\\&|[^&])*/s', 
                     implode('', $this->Grecko->Input->Server('argv')), 
                     $Args, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($Args);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => hfghfg=hfghfg&gfdgdf=4343543&gfdgfdgfd=fsdfds\&hghg999
            [1] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: The string you're trying to parse looks like the GET part of a url.  If that's the case, you might want to try PHP's `parse_str()` function http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: @dnagirl parse_str thing \& is a new value and don'T escape it.

Comment: @DavidBélanger I've added an answer that properly uses `parse_str` to parse the given input string, since `\&` can be properly encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is `preg_split()` rather than `preg_match_all()`.

```
$str = 'hfghfg=hfghfg&gfdgdf=4343543&gfdgfdgfd=fsdfds\&hghg999';
$res = preg_split('/(?<!\\\)&/', $str);

print_r($res);

/*
Array
(
  [0] => hfghfg=hfghfg
  [1] => gfdgdf=4343543
  [2] => gfdgfdgfd=fsdfds\&hghg999
)
*/
```

Comment: Better idea, better regex. +1

Comment: Please don't forget to mention the fact that the backslashes need to be double escaped because of the way PHP interpolates the string before passing it to PCRE, as this is the original problem.

Comment: Thanks, working better than my original code since I don't see null value after each line. Thakns !

Answer (score 1):

I'm will willing to bet the problem is that you forgot to add the additional backslashes needed to compensate for the fact that `\` is also the escape character in PHP.

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:\\\\&|[^&])*/s', implode('', $this->Grecko->Input->Server('argv')), $Args, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($Args);
```

**EDIT**

Indeed that is the problem - [See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/TnJbgD)

Comment: Thanks for poingting me to the solution, you were right, but bsdnoobz has an improvement to my need ! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe DaveRandom is correct, however here is an alternative way to parse the given string without using a regular expression.

It just encodes the `\&` as `%26`, which is the URL encoded value for an ampersand. Then, it uses [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/parse_str) to parse the input string.

```
$str = "hfghfg=hfghfg&gfdgdf=4343543&gfdgfdgfd=fsdfds\&hghg999";

// Properly encode the ampersand
$str = str_replace( '\&', '%26', $str);

// Parse the string
parse_str( $str, $arr);

var_dump( $arr);
```

**Output:**

```
array(3) {
  ["hfghfg"]=>
  string(6) "hfghfg"
  ["gfdgdf"]=>
  string(7) "4343543"
  ["gfdgfdgfd"]=>
  string(14) "fsdfds&hghg999"
}
```

I'm not sure if it is necessary, but you could then run [`urldecode`](http://www.php.net/urldecode) on each value of the resulting array with [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/array_map).

**Edit:**

If you want to keep the ampersand escaped, you can simply replace the ampersand with its escape, as so:

```
array_walk( $arr, 
    function( &$str) { 
        $str = str_replace( '&', '\&', $str);
});
```

This yields:

```
array(3) {
  ["hfghfg"]=>
  string(6) "hfghfg"
  ["gfdgdf"]=>
  string(7) "4343543"
  ["gfdgfdgfd"]=>
  string(15) "fsdfds\&hghg999"
}
```

Comment: Not a bad shout this, but unfortunately the `str_replace( '\&', '%26', $str);` approach is likely too simple. If one is using backslash as an escape character, normally one would use the double backslash to specify a literal one, and the simple `str_replace()` does not account for that. You would still need regex to take care of the `\&` substitutions - but this approach still has it's merits even then as it will parse to an associative key/value array, instead of leaving data that requires further parsing.

Comment: Would be a charm to use this, but it doesn't keep the caracter escaped. However, you have the right to win +1